# Model highly autocorrelated time series data

Tags: regression, time-series, autocorrelation

I have 1.5 year of data. Each value represent 15 minute interval. I am trying to predict the values for the next day (next 96 values, because 96*15 minutes = 24 hours). Below is the original data plot and auto correlation plot.

[image: Original complete data]
[image: Autocorrelation]

Currently I use linear regression with the following features: past data with different lag (2,3,4,5,6), past averages with different lag (2,3,4,5,6), past differences with different lag (2,3,4,5,6), past minimums with different lag (2,3,4,5,6) and past maximums with different lag (2,3,4,5,6). I also use a combination of categorical features from date (season, weekday, hour..).

Is my interpretation correct that lagged data up to 5.000 lag is very relevant (auto correlation is bigger than 0.5)? Does that mean that I have to make features for every lag up to 5.000? For example, should I have a feature with lagged values of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...5.000 and lagged averages, differences, minimums, maximums between 1-2, 1-3, 1-4...1-5.000, 2-3, 2-4, 2-5, 2-6, ... 2-5.000?

Are there any other "popular" models or features for this type of problem? I tried ARIMA, but it is very slow for this amount of data.

Comment: Just a note about functional form here.  A normal distribution implies that learning is happening, that is prior errors will vanish.  It doesn't appear that prior errors are really vanishing.  Differencing isn't going to matter because your model has an incredible amount of path dependence.  Is there a natural explanation for this?  Does it make sense that the system has long memory?